# How to get a node by his id

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, neomodel

So I have the id of a node and I want to get the node.
For example I have the ID 1 and I want to print out the name of the node with the ID 1.

I mean btw the "internal" ID of neo4j: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you want to do it.  In neomodel, I think `StructuredNode` class instances have a `._id` field.  So if you have a node in memory, you can get its ID that way.

If you don't have a node that way, you can use cypher and the `id()` function:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE (a:Foo {label: "Hello"}), (b:Foo {label: "Goodbye"});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 2
Properties set: 2
Labels added: 2
1985 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (f:Foo) return id(f);
+-------+
| id(f) |
+-------+
| 0     |
| 1     |
+-------+
2 rows
324 ms
```

**Edit** Access by ID:

```
MATCH (n) where id(n) = 1 return n;

MATCH (n) where id(n) IN [1,2] return n;
```